In theory, could you use Induction on any countable set?
Let $A$ be a countable set, not necessarily finite. Suppose I had some property P and I wanted to prove $\forall x \in A(P(x))$ By the general algorithm, If the first element of $A$ has such a property, the $n$th element of $A$ has such a property and the next element after it has such a property then every element in $A$ has the property. This seems logical, but I haven't seen it being used outside of $\mathbb{N}$. Why?

The ordering matters since you need a least elements and a successor operator. Once you have those it's going to be in a bijection to the naturals anyway. Like you could conceive of a way to do this with the rationals but you'd need a non-standard ordering since the rationals lacks successors and a least element in the usual order.

Your set needs a well-defined notion of a "next" element, since induction's key feature is that, if $P(k)$ is true, then so is $P(\text{successor}(k))$. For $\mathbb{N}$, that successor is $k+1$. In $\frac{1}{10} \mathbb{N}$ it would be $k+ \frac{1}{10}$. But you can't work in $\mathbb{Q}$ since it's too dense - there is no "next rational" after $0$ for instance.

These are answers to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.

I personally don't feel my comment is sufficiently thorough to warrant an answer, nor am I particularly interested in fleshing it out further; I'd rather reserve that to someone who is a little more familiar with the technical details than I feel I am.

For induction to be well-founded you need a well-ordered set or well-founded relation. $\ \ $

@MartinBrandenburg Well, I tried to create an Answer but it got quickly downvoted without further explanation. I see this kind of thing more and more often lately. No wonder people are hesitant to give Answers and choose to just leave a Comment instead.

In theory, yes. If $S$ is a countable set, then there is a surjective mapping $s$ from the natural numbers (where we can exclude $0$) to $S$. So based on this $s$ we can now use induction to show that all elements of $S$ have some property $P$ (i.e. $\forall x (x \in S \to P(x))$ by doing exactly what you propose: show that the 'first' element has that property (i.e. show that $P(s(1))$), and show that whenever the $n$-th element has property $P$, then the 'next' element has that property (i.e. $\forall n (P(s(n)) \to P(s(n+1)))$). Or, in full, we have:
$$(P(s(1)) \land \forall n (P(s(n)) \to P(s(n+1)))) \to \forall x (x \in S \to P(x))$$
So yes, you can totally do that. In theory. But, here is the likely problem, and why you don’t see much of that in practice. For many sets, whatever linear order you come up with for that set is likely not very conducive to a nice inductive argument.
For example, the set of rational numbers is countable. Now, there are many mapping from the natural numbers to the rational numbers. Here is an easy one: First, let's create all pairs of positive whole numbers that add up to $2$, then to $3$, etc. So you get $$(1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (1,3), (2,2), (3,1), (1,4), (2,3), (3,2), (4,1), ...etc. $$
We can treat these pairs as rational numbers:
$$\frac{1}{1}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{1}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{2}, \frac{3}{1}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{4}{1}, ...etc. $$
Notice that every positive rational number is guaranteed to show up in this list at some point, and so we know that the set of all positive rational numbers is countable. And we immediately get a list of all negative rational numbers too:
$$-\frac{1}{1}, -\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{2}{1}, -\frac{1}{3}, -\frac{2}{2}, -\frac{3}{1}, -\frac{1}{4}, -\frac{2}{3}, -\frac{3}{2}, -\frac{4}{1}, ...etc. $$
And finally, by splicing these two lists, and putting a $0$ in front, we get a list of all rational numbers:
$$0, \frac{1}{1}, -\frac{1}{1}, \frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{1}, -\frac{2}{1}, \frac{1}{3}, -\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{2}, -\frac{2}{2}, \frac{3}{1}, -\frac{3}{1}, ...etc. $$
(note that the list of rational numbers thus obtained contains duplicate elements, e.g. $\frac{1}{1}=\frac{2}{2}$. Is that a problem? No, not for what you want to do: as long as you can show that all elements in the list have some property $P$, then clearly all rational numbers have property $P$)
OK, so we know that the set of all rational numbers is countable. Easy peasy. Moreover, let $q$ be the function that maps the non-zero natural numbers to the rational numbers. Note that this function is not trivial to define with a closed formula, but with a little effort it can be done. So far so good.
But now here's the real issue: what is it about the $n$-th entry of this list having property $P$ that would imply that the $n+1$-th entry of this list has property $P$? It all depends on what that property $P$ is that you are considering, but likely there is really no clear connection between $P(q(n))$ and $P(q(n+1))$.
And this is something that will generally be true. Yes, for any countable set $S$ there is some function $s$ that maps natural numbers to that set, but it is unlikely that there is a nice logical relationship between $P(s(n))$ and $P(s(n+1))$ that you can exploit to become part of an inductive proof to show that all elements of $S$ have property $P$. So that is why in practice you rarely, if ever, see this kind of method being used.
A final note: All of the above is not to say that there are no practical methods of induction for countable sets other than the natural numbers. As Bill Dubuque in the Comments points out, you can use various descent methods, e.g. Fermat famously used infinite descent to show that there are no whole numbers $a,b,c$ such that $a^n+b^n=c^n$ for $n=3$ or $n=4$.  But note that in such cases you are not exploiting any kind of linear or total ordering on the set, but rather exploit a more general well-founded relationship, and thus use a form of the more general well-founded induction.
But my point in this Answer is to argue that the way you were suggesting to use induction, where you have a 'first' element, and always a 'next' element (i.e. by exploiting some kind of well- ordering on the set), is likely not going to work very well.

You gotta love those downvotes that provide no explanation. Really, what is so bad about this answer?

So if a field is well-ordered and countable, induction would be a viable method of proving properties in said field?

@FrancisAugustus Probably not, because - as this answer states - induction probably isn't going to succeed unless the well-ordering is somehow "natural" (that is, related to the field structure). And this is very stringent. Think, for example, about how you would well-order even such a nice field as $\mathbb{Q}$ so that field-theoretic properties pass nicely from each number to its successor in the ordering.

@Francis Beware - this answer is misleading. There are imany methods of induction (or descent) that prove useful for rationals, e.g. denominator descent, or Farey / mediant descent in the Stern-Brocot tree, etc. $\ \ $

@BillDubuque True, but I was not suggesting that induction does never work nicely for rational numbers or other sets other than the  natural numbers. I was just commenting on the particular kind of (linear) induction that the OP was hoping to use as imposed by the fact that the set is countable. But thanks for your comment, and I added this clarification to my Answer!
